# Nokogiri Error: undefined method `radiobutton_with' - Why?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I try to access a form using mechanize (Ruby).
On my form I have a gorup of Radiobuttons.
So I want to check one of them.

I wrote:

```
target_form = (page/:form).find{ |elem| elem['id'] == 'formid'}
target_form.radiobutton_with(:name => "radiobuttonname")[2].check
```

In this line I want to check the radiobutton with the value of 2.
But in this line, I get an error:

```
: undefined method `radiobutton_with' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x9b86ea> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: According to the docs, your form should be of `Mechanize::Form` class, not `Nokogiri::XML::Element`. How did you get `target_form`?

Comment: target_form:
target_form = (page/:form).find { |elem| elem['id'] == 'formid'}

Comment: You should use `Mechanize::Page#form_with` method to get the form. BTW, I am not sure that your page is `Mechanize::Page` at all.

Comment: page = agent.get('http://www.mypage.xy')
thats how i define page

Comment: puts page.class will return WWW::Mechanize::Page

Now I tried catching my form tag with xpath, cause there is no other way i know to get an element by id:
target_form = page.search '//*[@id="myformid"]'
puts target_form.class will return 
Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Comment: The easiest way I was able to find a Mechanize form by id is `page.forms.find{|f| f.form_node['id'] == 'myformid'}`

Comment: Well, using your way, catching the form, i get another error:

: undefined method `[]' for #<WWW::Mechanize::Form::RadioButton:0xe72f0c> (NoMethodError)

at line:
target_form.radiobutton_with(:name => "radiobuttonname")[2].check

Don't know why, but my form is still a WWW::Mechanize::Page Object as before, but now it seems to go on a little more.

Comment: I presume you have multiple radiobuttons with the same name, and you need the third. In that case, just call `radiobuttons_with` instead of `radiobutton_with` method (note the plural).

Answer (score 6):

The problem occured because using a Mechanize page as a Nokogiri document (by calling the `/` method, or `search`, or `xpath`, etc.) returns Nokogiri elements, not Mechanize elements with their special methods.

As noted in the comments, you can be sure to get a `Mechanize::Form` by using the [`form_with`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Page.html#M000178) method to find your form instead.

Sometimes, however, you can find the element you want with Nokogiri but not with Mechanize. For example, consider a page with a `<select>` element that is not inside a `<form>`. Since there is no form, you can't use the Mechanize [`field_with`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Form.html#M000138) method to find the select and get a `Mechanize::Form::SelectList` instance.

If you have a Nokogiri element and you want the Mechanize equivalent, you can create it by passing the Nokogiri element to the constructor. For example:

```ruby
sel = Mechanize::Form::SelectList.new( page.at_xpath('//select[@name="city"]') )
```

In your case where you had a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` and wanted a `Mechanize::Form`:

```ruby
# Find the xml element
target_form = (page/:form).find{ |elem| elem['id'] == 'formid'}
target_form = Mechanize::Form.new( target_form )
```

*P.S. The first line above is more simply achieved by* `target_form = page.at_css('#formid')`.

Comment: To actually be able to submit the form you would have to change your last line to `target_form = Mechanize::Form.new(target_form, mech_object, page)`

Comment: @raphinesse Oh? I'll take your word for it. What is the `mech_object` object?

Comment: Your 'agent', the `Mechanize` object. See [Mechanize::Form#new docs](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-c-new) for more details. If you take a look at [Mechanize::Form#submit's source](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-submit) you'll notice that it tries to call `@mech.submit` which will fail when no `mech` argument was provided. The same is true for the `page` argument I guess.

Comment: One last thing: In the most recent version of Mechanize there seems to be no `Mechanize::Page#at_css`. `Mechanize::Page#at` works fine however...